# routing does not work in asp.net mvc with angular

Tags: angularjs

Hello I m creating an angularJs SPA project with asp.net mvc. I want to implement angular routing in m project so I m trying to change the routes via angular routing. this is my code.

Angular routes.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'myApp.ctrl.testCtrl'

])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/test', { templateUrl: '/home/test', controller: 'testCtrl'})
}]);
```

My controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.ctrl.testCtrl', [])
.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function () {
    console.log('in Controller');
}])
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now When I write

```
<a href="#/test">TestPage</a>
```

also tried

```
<a href="/#/test">TestPage</a>
```

but none of these works.

The Url changes to

```
 http://localhost:57026/#!#%2Ftest
```

so the routing does not work. Please point me out where i m going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should write an ng-click event on anchor tag

```
<a href="#" ng-click="clickFunction()">TestPage</a>
```

And in click function use in controller

```
$scope.clickFunction = function(){
      $location.path("/test");
}
```